# ¿Como creo un widget que muestre los días que faltan hasta el día de mi cumpleaños en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-widget

Trabajo con Android Studio y tengo que crear un widget que muestre los días que faltan hasta el día de mi cumpleaños, y crear una actividad de configuración que permita elegir la fecha “destino” de la cuenta atrás. Yo se crear un widget básico, con un texto, lo que no se es que código tengo que utilizar para que muestre los días que faltan y configurar el widget.

Muchas gracias. Abajo PEGO el codigo.

- ControlWidget.java

Aquí se puede cambiar el contenido del Widget, actualizar, etc.

```
package ramon.campusccc.widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Created by Ramón on 15/03/2017.
 */

public class ControlWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

- primerwidget.xml

Aquí encontramos el apartado visual del Widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:text="Primer WIDGET"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</FrameLayout>
```

- primerwidget_provider.xml

Este archivo se ha creado dentro de R/xml y es el fichero de configuración del Widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/primerwidget"
    android:minWidth="75dp"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"

    />
```

Como puedes ver es un método básico para construir un widget, falta el código importante.

Comment: Hola Ramon, puedes poner el codigo del widget y lo que has intentado? Asi es muy amplio. Un saludo

Comment: Pues te explico, en realidad no hay mucho código que añadir. Prácticamente está vacío. Solo he creado un xml para el widget, otro xml para la configuración del widget, y el archivo .java para actualizar, etc.

Comment: @lois6b acabo de copiar el código